# How convert string date to unix format with moment

Tags: date, momentjs

i have this date of String type : `14-03-2019` and i need convert this in unix format.

this my code in javascript:

```
let time = moment(time).unix();
```

but moment response me with this error:

> deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non RFC2822/ISO date formats are discouraged and will be removed in an upcoming major release. Please refer to http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info.
>   Arguments:
>   [0] _isAMomentObject: true, _isUTC: false, _useUTC: false, _l: undefined, _i: 14-03-2019, _f: undefined, _strict: undefined, _locale: [object Object]
>   Error
>       at Function.createFromInputFallback (/Users/Hernan/Haip/haip/node_modules/moment/moment.js:320:98)
>       at configFromString (/Users/Hernan/Haip/haip/node_modules/moment/moment.js:2368:15)
>       at configFromInput (/Users/Hernan/Haip/haip/node_modules/moment/moment.js:2594:13)
>       at prepareConfig (/Users/Hernan/Haip/haip/node_modules/moment/moment.js:2577:13)
>       at createFromConfig (/Users/Hernan/Haip/haip/node_modules/moment/moment.js:2544:44)
>       at createLocalOrUTC (/Users/Hernan/Haip/haip/node_modules/moment/moment.js:2631:16)
>       at createLocal (/Users/Hernan/Haip/haip/node_modules/moment/moment.js:2635:16)
>       at hooks (/Users/Hernan/Haip/haip/node_modules/moment/moment.js:12:29)
>       at createTagChart (/Users/Hernan/Haip/haip/server/components/utils/index.js:36:18)
>       at Function.getInfluecerSearched (/Users/Hernan/Haip/haip/server/api/campaign-engine/campaign.model.js:439:39)
>       at process.internalTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:77:7)

and return a `NAN`

How can convert my string to unix format with moment ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your date format does not follow the **[ISO_8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)** format you need to provide the input date format to the moment constructor. In your case it appears to be 'DD-MM-YYYY' format and not one of the ISO date time formats, specifically just for date it would be `YYYY-MM-DD`.

So you need to provide the custom input format as the second argument to the moment constructor.

```
let time = moment(time, 'DD-MM-YYYY').unix(); // should output the correct value
```

However i suggest you should try to aim to get the source date-time to be in a standard ISO format than an arbitrary custom date format string as much as possible.